# Weex Library Crash on Android

Tags: weex

I am getting this random crash in weex on android platform.

Weex version details-
   v1.3.8
 - weexpack : v1.2.3
 - weex-builder : v0.4.0
 - weex-previewer : v1.5.1

```
Facing a crash in sdk : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.taobao.weex.ui.flat.WidgetContainer com.taobao.weex.ui.flat.FlatGUIContext.getFlatComponentAncestor(com.taobao.weex.ui.component.WXComponent)' on a null object reference
        at com.taobao.weex.ui.component.WXComponent.setComponentLayoutParams(WXComponent.java:559)
        at com.taobao.weex.ui.component.WXComponent.setLayout(WXComponent.java:551)
        at com.taobao.weex.ui.RenderActionContextImpl.setLayout(RenderActionContextImpl.java:82)
        at com.taobao.weex.ui.WXRenderManager.setLayout(WXRenderManager.java:150)
        at com.taobao.weex.dom.DOMActionContextImpl$ApplyUpdateConsumer$1.execute(DOMActionContextImpl.java:276)
        at com.taobao.weex.ui.WXRenderManager$1.run(WXRenderManager.java:104)
        at com.taobao.weex.common.WXThread$SafeRunnable.run(WXThread.java:48)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed, not released yet. You can build from source if emergency.

Comment: Any turnaround time when are we planning to release it?

Comment: in early August, 2018, I think.

Comment: Can you please suggest any quick fix to solve it currently without building from source?

Comment: Update to latest version of weex, your version is out of date, I think